# Angular ngView with CKEditor disappearing text

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ckeditor, ng-view

cutting right to the chase here heh

Building an admin backend system with angular for a client. This site and backend are built with Node and Angular.  I've got a post editor setup, so that when you click a link to edit a post, locationProvider and ngRoute go to work and swap out the partial with a new controller, and updates the url.

Here at this point, everything shows up perfectly.

It's when I click on Cancel (which is a standard link going back to the post list view) or submit (which works it's magic and then redirects to the same url as cancel)  and this works.

It's when I click on the link to edit the same post again.  The content that's supposed to be in the CKEditor is blank. However when using Chrome Dev Tools I can see that tw original input field has the content in it correctly, but the iframe has nothing in it at all but the CKEditor Chrome.

As for code,

In my controller it looks like this:

```
$scope.post = null;
$http.get('/api/post/'+$routeParams.id)
.success(function(data,status,headers){
    $scope.post = data;
});
$(function() {
     CKEDITOR.replace("content");
});

$scope.submit = function() { 
    // submission code here
};
```

Pretty basic here, just want to get the basics out of the way first.

Is the problem with how I'm loading CKEditor?

Comment: I apologize for any jankiness, I wrote this question using my phone. But this is unapologetically the approach I had written before leaving home today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CKEDITOR.replace("content")` would replace the html element with CKEditor instance. Assuming "content" is some div id or text area in your html.

To set the content you need to use

```
CKEDITOR.instances["content"].setData("Contents to be displayed in text area");
```

Comment: Not a bad idea! I'll give that a shot